# How to convert this complex json with same key names of array type to pojo classes

Tags: rest-assured, pojo

I have this json response schema which i want to convert into the pojo class so that i can iterate the values in items field and assert them

```
{
    "layout": {
        "items": [
            {
                "type": "app",
                "app_package": "com.android.vending"
            },





            {
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "app",
                        "app_package": "com.android.camera2"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "app",
                        "app_package": "com.bluestacks.settings"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "app",
                        "app_package": "com.android.chrome"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "app",
                        "app_package": "com.bluestacks.filemanager"
                    }
                ],
                "type": "folder"
            },




            {
                "type": "app",
                "app_package": "com.bluestacks.gamecenter"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

When I am trying to create the pojo class for this then the items array inside items array then it does not works